# How do I make a trait that is restricted to types who implement another trait where `&Self` self is a trait's type?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

For instance, I want every `MyTrait` to implement `AddAssign<&'a Self>`. This is as far as I got, after placing `'a` where the compiler wanted:

```rs
trait MyTrait<'a>: 'a + std::ops::AddAssign<&'a Self> {}

fn func<'a, T: MyTrait<'a>>(a: &mut T, b: T) {
    *a += &b;
}
```

This code fails with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:11
  |
3 | fn func<'a, T: MyTrait<'a>>(a: &mut T, b: T) {
  |         -- lifetime `'a` defined here
4 |     *a += &b;
  |           ^^
  |           |
  |           borrowed value does not live long enough
  |           requires that `b` is borrowed for `'a`
5 | }
  | - `b` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

How do I tell the compiler that `&b` will only be used for the duration of that sum?

Comment: To answer your question, just use `b: &'a T` instead of `b: T`. However, I think what you probably actually want to do (a version of `AddAssign` that takes a reference instead of a value) sadly just isn't possible due to the way `AddAssign` is defined. You'll find that if you just use `b: &T`, it seems to work at first, but you'll run into the issue that it's not really possible to implement `MyTrait<'a>` with an arbitrary lifetime for non-`Copy` types, which defeats the whole point of using a reference in the first place.

Comment: In my real code, I can't  have `b: &'a T`, because the variable I am summing is local. I specifically need a solution where `b` can go out of scope before `a`. It may not be possible due to syntax limitation, but I don't see how it is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: It wouldn't be sound because implementors of `AddAssign` can assume that the addend lives forever; for example if references were allowed, you could implement `AddAssign` to push the reference to an internal stack which would persist after the reference becomes invalid. My recommendation: create your own version of `AddAssign` that uses references instead.

Comment: [Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82d197b04e28385c3e8dcc99ef87eb16)

Comment: @Coder-256 answering your question, "If we had `foo += &bar`, what happens to `foo.vec` when `bar` is dropped?", then `foo` would have to be dropped before `bar`, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with that. But such trait implementation wouldn't match my trait constraint, now that I fixed it with the answer from @kmdreko. In my original attempt, I said the referenced object must outlive `MyTrait` object, but in the accepted answer there is no such restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [higher-ranked trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) to make the constraint generic over the lifetime so it isn't constrained to using the one defined on the trait:

```
pub trait MyTrait: for<'a> std::ops::AddAssign<&'a Self> {}
                // ^^^^^^^
```